# I have added cells to my table and i set attributes for each cell as below

Tags: javascript

```
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
cell1.setAttribute('name',1);
cell2.setAttribute('name',2);
cell3.setAttribute('name',3);
```

I have link field in cell cell1 on each row, how can i know on which row i clicked that link? please help me.